# Add hidden form table row to end of form with variable for many tables with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have successfully used this code to add a row to a table From a hidden row.

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
$("#dispadd").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#hiddenrow')
        .clone()
            .removeAttr('id')
            .show()
            .appendTo( $('#table1').after().show() 
        );
    });
});
```

Here is my "add" button code..

```
<img src="images/plus.png"  style="cursor:pointer " title="Add" id="dispadd" >
```

My problem is that I have a MULTITUDE of tables and forms on this particular page so I need to use passed variables to the above code to allow for the MULTITUDE, but I don't know JQUERY well enough to get it done...  Somehow I need to pas these parameters to the script so it can be used for all cases.

The id of the "add" Button Now is static as "dispadd"  but  I want to pass it to the script as dipAdd (a variable)
The id of the "hidden row" Now is static as "hiddenrow" but  I want to pass it to the script as hiddenRow (a variable)
The id of the table Now is static as "table1"  but  I want to pass it to the script as tableVar (a variable).

Please help me to modify this script to accept these variables.
Thanks in advance for all your help and consideration.
MrTom

Comment: If you explain exactly what you're trying to do, and why it's not working, it would be easier to help you out. I suspect you're really looking for scope, context and `this` to target the parent form of each button etc ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you want but try this:

```
<img src="images/plus.png"  style="cursor:pointer " title="Add" id="1" onclick="dispadd(this.id)">
```

and then

```
function dispadd(id, event) {
event.preventDefault();
$('#hiddenrow')
    .clone()
        .removeAttr('id')
        .show()
        .appendTo( $('#table'+id).after().show() 
    );
});
```

Let mew know if this isn't what you want because it seems this is an easy problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this if you want to pass elements as variables, not sure if this helps

```
function(dipAdd,hiddenRow)
{
$("#" + dipAdd).click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#' + hiddenRow)
        .clone()
            .removeAttr('id')
            .show()
            .appendTo( $('#table1').after().show() 
        );
    });
}
```